# pip external headers only for build

Tags: c++, github, dependencies, setup.py

To compile my python package I use [pybind11](https://github.com/wjakob/pybind11), which is an header-only C++ library.

I would like to download the master (or some other branch) in `setup.py` such that I can include it while compiling.

How do I do that?

Basically I would like the equivalent of something like `git clone https://github.com/wjakob/pybind11.git _ext/pybind11`.

Here is my setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

cxxpart = Extension('mymodule.cxxpart',
                    include_dirs = ['_ext/pybind11/include'],
                    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
                    sources = ['src/cxxpart.cpp'])
setup(
    name = "mymodule",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
    ext_modules = [cxxpart],

    install_requires = ['Flask'],
)
```

Note that I would like to get the master and not the version on pypi.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked but perhaps helpful: the pybind organization on github has an [example](https://github.com/pybind/python_example) whose setup.py creates a dependency on pybind11. This ensures that installing your extension will first cause pybind11 to be installed (via pip & PyPi).